# AttributeError: module 'keras' has no attribute 'Input'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

On my `Keras`(1.2.2), I tried to run code with a function [Input](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/input/),

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(img_size[0], img_size[1], 1))
```

But the following error returned

```
AttributeError: module 'keras' has no attribute 'Input'
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: How do you import keras? Is it `tf.keras` installed with Tensorflow, or the separate `keras` package? (`tf.keras.Input` would work)

Comment: It is a separate `keras` package

Comment: Then see M Z's answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `keras.layers.Input`. All layers are under the submodule `keras.layers`. Like:

```py
inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(img_size[0], img_size[1], 1))
```

Another common thing to do is to say

```py
from keras.layers import Input
```

This way later in your code it doesn't get too messy when you try to add a bunch of layers to your model:

```py
inputs = Input(shape=(img_size[0], img_size[1], 1))
```

Answer (score -1):

try it `from tensorflow.keras.layers import InputLayer` or `from tensorflow.keras.layers import *`
should work